# (Discord.js) How to get a full list of Members instead of only the cached ones

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to export a full list of Members, including offline ones into a .csv using the code below. Using "message.guild.members" though, I only catch the cached Members. How could I change it to get everybody, non-cached Members included?

```js
const auditUsers = (message) => {
    console.log(message)
    let allMembers = []
    for (let m of message.guild.members.values()){
        if (m.user.bot == true) continue
        let member = {
            Name: m.user.username,
            Tag: m.user.tag,
            UserID: `<@${m.user.id}>`,
            JoinDate: m.joinedAt.toDateString()
        }
        let memberRoles = []
        for (let r of m.roles.values()){
            if (r.name != "@everyone") memberRoles.push(r.name)
        }
        member.Roles = memberRoles.join(', ')
        allMembers.push(member)
    }

    const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser()
    const csv = json2csvParser.parse(allMembers)
    fs.writeFileSync(`./${message.guild.name}_audit.csv`, csv, {flag: 'w'}, function(err){
        if (err) consoleLog('Error saving CSV file:' + err.message, "ERR")
    })
}
```

Source: https://github.com/awwbots/Dis-GuildAudit-CSV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run [`fetchMembers()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMembers) first before accessing the users.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Jesus. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still pretty new to programming languages but I try and take notes and learn where I am able to.

The command `fetchMembers()`, do you enter this in your terminal before running `npm start`?

Also, I went with the original code base as per the Git repo and it dropped a neat CSV file with all members, their usernames, tags, roles, join dates, etc. in my desired folder. Beauty! But at the end of the terminal output I received this error nonetheless and I am wondering what it could mean

```
2023-09-22 15:54:37 [INFO](audit): Allowed command audit from enzocrypto on the Wildxyz server.
/Users/enzo/Documents/Dis-GuildAudit-CSV/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:79
              new DiscordAPIError(res.request.path, res.body, res.request.method) : err);
              ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at /Users/enzo/Documents/Dis-GuildAudit-CSV/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:79:15
    at /Users/enzo/Documents/Dis-GuildAudit-CSV/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  path: '/api/v7/channels/1092514564689641592/messages/1154807974590693398',
  code: 50013,
  method: 'DELETE'
}
```